# On OS X how do I set desired language in git-gui?

Tags: git, git-gui

Its almost not possible to use in my native language, swedish. I have seen some tips for windows, but not for OS X.

Comment: This one didn't help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427785/how-to-set-desired-language-in-git-gui

Comment: here's a solution for msysgit, should also work on OS X: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=302