# How to change git's language in IntelliJ's built-in terminal?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

This just started happening to me today in IntelliJ's terminal all of a sudden.

git's command line interface is in Russian now. For example, `git status` returns something like:

```
Изменения, которые не в индексе для коммита:
  (используйте «git add <файл>…», чтобы добавить файл в индекс)
  (используйте «git checkout -- <файл>…», чтобы отменить изменения
   в рабочем каталоге)

        изменено: whatever/filename.kt
```

If I run git from the macOS's Terminal app, the CLI is in English, as expected.

I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition 2018.2.3 on macOS 10.12.6 and haven't changed any of my settings except upgrading git to 2.19.0 and the Kotlin plugin to v1.2.70 today.

It's not that I don't understand Russian, it's just I've been using English UI for years, and this sudden change is unnecessary and throws me off. Is there a way to change it back?

Edit: I've downgraded git version via `brew switch git 2.18.0` and it's back to English CLI. Weird. Still trying to figure out why `git` switches to Russian in v2.19. macOS's GUI, preferred language, primary input source are all `English` on my laptop, and the region is set to `United States`.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427785/how-to-set-desired-language-in-git-gui/1427938

Comment: I've seen a similar question but my issue is IntelliJ related, I believe. I don't have this issue in macOS's Terminal, nor VS Code's built-in terminal.

Comment: Don't know the root cause, but one solution was posted here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337244

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the exact same issue after upgrade git using home-brew from 2.18 to 2.19, I am using IntelliJ 2018.2.

Terminal comes with OS X is working fine => `git status` showing english

Terminal embedded with IntelliJ is not => `git status` showing Chinese

Followed https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337244 and deleted other preferred languages leaving only English (U.S) seems solved the problem.

The issue looks like IntelliJ is not passing down the LC_LANG correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Removing Russian from the list of preferred languages in the "Language & Region" preferences pane did the trick.

Comment: It freaked me out when my git started talking French, thanks.